# Global Invalid Hook Call - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I recently started working with React, and I'm trying to understand why my `context.js` is giving me so much trouble. Admittedly I'm not great with JavaScript to start, so I'd truly appreciate any insight.

Thank you, code and the error that it generates:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';

const AppContext = React.createContext(undefined, undefined);



const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isSidebarOpen, setIsSidebarOpen] = useState(false);

  const openSidebar = () => {
    setIsSidebarOpen(true);
  };

  const closeSidebar = () => {
    setIsSidebarOpen(false);
  };

    const toggle = () => {
        if (isSidebarOpen) {
            closeSidebar();
        } else {
            openSidebar();
        }
    };

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        isSidebarOpen,
        openSidebar,
        closeSidebar,
          toggle
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};



export const useGlobalContext = () => {
  return useContext(AppContext);
};

export { AppContext, AppProvider };
```

Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Thank you again for taking the time to look!

**EDIT: Sidebar App Added for context (double entendre!)**

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg'
import {links} from './data'
import {FaTimes} from 'react-icons/fa'

import { useGlobalContext } from "./context";


const Sidebar = () => {
    const { toggle, isSidebarOpen } = useGlobalContext();
    return (
        <aside className={`${isSidebarOpen ? 'sidebar show-sidebar' : 'sidebar'}`}>
            <div className='sidebar-header'>
                <img src={logo} className='logo' alt='NavTask Management'/>
                <button className='close-btn' onClick={toggle}>
                    <FaTimes />
                </button>
            </div>
            <ul className='links'>
                {links.map((link) => {
                    const { id, url, text, icon } = link;
                    return (
                        <li key={id}>
                            <a href={url}>
                                {icon}
                                {text}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    );
                })}
            </ul>
        </aside>
    );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: Can you post code of where you use `AppProvider`?

Comment: yes of course, give me a sec

Comment: all set @ElanHamburger !

Comment: Do you wrap your app with AppProvider?

Comment: yes! @chonnychu

Comment: well, I can't see the problem... could you post all of the code into a online IDE such as codesandbox and let me test it?

Comment: of course @chonnychu